# Trying to make a chat app in android studio but I am unable to append the texts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

Chat.java :

My app only shows the last message typed and shows in the ChatWindow. My firebase Database gets the messages but i am unable to show the same to the user in my app. I want to show at least 5-10 previous messages to the user.

```
    public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference Database;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        final UserLocalStore localStore = new UserLocalStore(Chat.this);
        Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
        final TextView Chat_Window=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.chat_window);
        Database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String s) {
                Log.e("DatasnapShot",dataSnapshot.getKey().toString());

                Chat_Window.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Button SendMessage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        SendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String messageText = Chat_Window.getText().toString();            
         Database.push().setValue((localStore.getUserData().get(0).toString()));
                Database.push().setValue(ChatType.getText().toString());
                Chat_Window.append(ChatType.getText().toString());
                ChatType.setText("");
            }
        });
            Button Signout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signout);
    {
        Signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            UserLocalStore localStore=new UserLocalStore(Chat.this);
            localStore.LogOut();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Chat.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } 
    }
}
```

My activity_chat.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/chat_type"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter message to send..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:text="Send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chat_type" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_window"
    android:layout_width="406dp"
    android:layout_height="566dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="Chat message wil appear here..."
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chat_type"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signout" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/signout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="324dp"
    android:text="Sign Out"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chat_window"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chat_window" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

A screentshot of the VirtualMobile:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plciy.jpg

[Firebase Database structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cts1g.jpg)

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). In the meanwhile, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Add also you .XML file and please also responde with @AlexMamo.

Comment: Added my xml file and firebase structure screenshot @AlexMamo

Comment: What is the result that you expect to be printed?

Comment: I want to show at least 5-10 previous messages to the user. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Chat_Window.setText("");
```

Add this line after you initialize `Chat_Window`.

```
Chat_Window.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

Change this line to -

```
Chat_Window.append("\n" + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

Comment: Is there also a way to show only a limited number of texts to the user. I mean whenever the user opens the app the server loads all the messages and thats not much efficient and takes up processing. How can I limit the number of texts shown at a time to like about to show the Last 15 messages? @Chirag Mittal

Comment: I would recommend you to implement queue data structure. I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/) useful.